# std::unordered_set of pointers

Tags: c++, hash, set

I have the following struct

```
struct MyClass {
    int myInt;
    std::map<int, int> myMap;
};
```

I want to use `unordered_set<MyClass*, PointedObjHash, PointedObEq>` but I can't find a valid way to declare `PointedObEq`.

I tried

```
struct PointedObjHash {
    size_t operator() (MyClass* const& c) const {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(seed, c->myInt);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, c->myMap);
        return seed;
    }
```

and I hope it is fine, but I can't find a way to declare `PointedObjEq`

--- EDIT ---

If declare operator== inside the class debug never breaks, but I think 'cause MyClass == MyClass* never happens...

```
struct MyClass {
    ...
    ...
    bool operator==(MyClass* const& c) {
        return this->myInt == c->myInt & this->myMap == c->myMap;
    }
```

Comment: Which errors/problems are you seeing? What have you tried?

Comment: You can declare `PointedObjEq` similar to your `PointedObjHash` but replacing with equal operator.

Comment: you may be aware this: Set of pointers leads unpredictable results.

Comment: @SatishChalasani It would behave well if the pointers are treated only as proxies for their values, i.e. if `PointedObjEq` compares `myInt` and `myMap`. (Given the hash, I think that's the only viable choice.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter agreed.

Comment: @inf edited my question

Comment: `std::rel_ops` provide reliable pointer comparision (regardless of what they point to), but what you want here is more subtle, a hashing function, that needs *canonical pointer values*, that are equal when casted to suitably large integer. I don't have the foggiest idea how to obtain canonical pointer values in a portable way.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf There's no pointer comparison at all.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Oh. Thanks. But then I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The problem here is definitely smaller than it appears at first glance :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If declare operator== inside the class debug never breaks, but I think 'cause MyClass == MyClass* never happens...

The `unordered_set` needs to use `operator==` (or `PointedObjEq`) to double-check the results of the hash function. The hash provides *approximate* equality, the equality function is used to weed out false positives.

If you've tested adding the same value to the set twice, then you've tested the equality function. To be sure, of course, you can have it print something to the console.

Since it's impossible to define an `operator==` function with two pointer operands, the `PointedObjEq` class will be necessary. Note that it takes a `MyClass const *` on both sides. Also, there's no need to use a reference to a pointer.

So,

```
struct PointedObjEq {
    bool operator () ( MyClass const * lhs, MyClass const * rhs ) const {
        return lhs->myInt == rhs->myInt
            && lhs->myMap == rhs->myMap;
    }
};
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that his comparison function is never even used? I.e. it defaults to `std::equal_to`, with normal pointer comparison, ignoring the `operator==` he added to his struct.

Comment: got it! I foolishly tried to declare operator== instead of operator(), that's why I couldn't find a way to compare 2 pointers!

Comment: P.S.: Your example code should use `struct` instead of `class` or make `operator()` public.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
struct PointedObEq {
    bool operator()(MyClass const * lhs, MyClass const * rhs) const {
        return lhs->myInt == rhs->myInt && lhs->myMap == rhs->myMap;
    }
};
```

The reason why your solution does not work is because you have effectively written a mechanism to compare a `MyClass` with a `MyClass*`, when you actually need something to compare a `MyClass*` with a `MyClass*`.

---

P.S.: My original answer passed the pointers by `const&`. Thinking about it, that's a strange coding style, so I changed it to pass the pointers by value.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef MyClass* PtrMyClass;

struct PointedObjCompare
{   // functor for operator==
    bool operator()(const PtrMyClass& lhs, const PtrMyClass& rhs) const
    {   
        // your code goes here
    }
};

std::unordered_set < MyClass*, PointedObjHash, PointedObjCompare > myset;
```

Comment: No idea why you got downvoted for this. I find your sample code most helpful. although some description (available in the other answers) could be helpful.